# pgpool connections get frozen

Tags: postgresql-9.1, connection, pgpool

I have installed pgpool 3.2.1 with 2 backends in streaming replication mode with load balancing and connections pool.I did some high load tests tring to colapse the pgpool connections.

Suposing that this rule is correct : max_pool*num_init_children <= (max_connections - superuser_reserved_connections)

Test 1:

num_init_children = 90
max_pool = 1

(only in the master)
max_connections = 100
superuser_reserved_connections = 3

Result for psql -U postgres -c 'SELECT COUNT from pg_stat_activity'  was 90.

Test 2:

num_init_children = 90
max_pool = 2

(only in the master)
max_connections = 100
superuser_reserved_connections = 3

Result for psql -U postgres -c 'SELECT COUNT from pg_stat_activity'  was 91. What happens with the other 6 connections to get up to 97 connections? which is the maximum number of connections I can get  to postgresql.

In both cases I get all connections used in pgpoolAdmin and the connection to database get frozen and no new connections were allowed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In pgpool they are using the following rule to control the connections:

max_pool*num_init_children <= (max_connections - superuser_reserved_connections) (no query canceling needed)
max_pool*num_init_children*2 <= (max_connections - superuser_reserved_connections) (query canceling needed)

So, the problem is when you have query cancelling you must set in postgresql the double number of connections configured in pgpool.